# find exec ls : No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, find, ls

I tried to execute:

`find ~/ -name "*foo*" -exec "ls -la {}" \;`

And it printed:

> find: 'ls -la /home/users/MyUser/fooBar': No such file or directory
>
> find: 'ls -la /home/users/MyUser/Barfoo': No such file or directory

Also `ls` is aliased to `ls --color`.

What kind of tricky trick happened here?

Comment: I don't need this alias, it was just to be precise.
You are right, please add your comment as an answer to this question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments of `-exec` should not be quoted. Remove the quotes after `-exec`. And `-exec` does not detect aliases so you need to pass the `--color` option to exec.